# QML TableView column headers width / Auto size headers to content

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to my TableView automatically resize column widths to the content. I do not declare columnWidthProvider and then it works perfect. But because I need to add column headers - I need to know what width the individual columns have. How I may get this column widths? Or basically, how I make column headers have the same width as columns? (Unfortunately the columns musn't have fixed width)

```
TableView {
    id: tableView
    anchors.fill: parent
    rowSpacing: -1
    columnSpacing: -1
    topMargin: 30
    clip: true
    model: bs_tablemodel
    
    delegate: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: delegateText.contentWidth + 40
        implicitHeight: delegateText.contentHeight + 20
        color: '#f5f5f5'
        border.width: 1        
        
        Text {
            id: delegateText
            text: display
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            //color: 'white'
            font.pixelSize: 15
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
    
    Row {
        id: columnsHeader
        y: tableView.contentY
        topPadding: -1
        bottomPadding: -1
        spacing: -1
        z: 2
        Repeater {
            model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
            
            Label {
                width: tableView.model.columnWidth(index)                   // HERE I NEED TO PASS COLUMN WIDTHS, DEPENDING ON COLUMN INDEX
                height: 30
                text: tableView.model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                color: "#050401"
                font.pixelSize: 15
                padding: 10
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "#f5f5f5"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? I tried working with the columnWidthProvider method, but I manage only to make the column of the table the same size of the column headers.